# Locate multiple class pointers at a string

Tags: c++

Ok this is extremely hard to explain. I tried to write a 100 line explanation in here, after I saw I failed I tried to create an image to better explain it which also failed http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/7383/48821020.png

It seems impossible because the complexity it extremely high. In the most raw is, I need to assign Id's for each part of a string. Currently I can assign Id's for a string example:

```
He: hey
She: Hi
He: What's up
She: Not much, you?
He: I'm fine, i'm selling a <Scale Armor> wanna buy it?
She: Next time maybe.
```

I can return `What's up` by using the function `CString szText = GetTextAtLine(3);` because `What's up` is located on the third line of the chat. Each line has an Id, the Id is the line number. Each line also has a pointer to a class named `CItemElem`. CItemElem holds all the information about an item.

I Locate the pointer by using the following function `CItemElem *pItem = GetItemAtLineId(5)`, it would return the a pointer stored at `map<unsigned int,CItemElem*>mItemChat` where `unsigned int` is the line indetifier. Everytime someone talks something in chat if an item has been input at the chat a new element is inserted into the STL map with it's line id.

```
CItemElem* CEditString::GetItemAtLineId( unsigned long uLine )
{

    for( map<unsigned int,CItemElem*>::iterator it = m_mItemChat.begin(); it != m_mItemChat.end(); ++it )
    {
        if( uLine == it->first )
            return( it->second );
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

So as you can see I can locate a `CItemElem` pointer by the line Id, but now my problem is I need to locate multiple items at the string because a max of 3 items can be input in a sentence at time:

```
He: Hey guys i'm selling <Scale Boots> <Wooden Sword> <Water Helmet> cool items!
```

Currently I can return only 1 item at a chat sentence at a time because I can locate the item by the line Id. I've been toasting my brain the past hours, please enlighten me how to be able to return more than one item at the same sentence Id.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is possible. I'm not totally sure, but `map<unsigned int, vector<CItemElem*>>` is probably what you need.

Comment: It has to be more specific because when the user mouseover the part of the string <Scale Boots> it must display the item information (hold at CItemElem*). It's ok to store multiple items at a line that way, the problem is locate what item is what on mouseovering

Comment: I'm not sure how you did the UI, but you have to create a separate "region"/"subview" for the special text, then assign the correct item information.

Comment: I thought about not only assigning to the map the line id but also the string position using your `vector<CitemElem*>` idea. Something like `struct strPos{ unsigned int uLineId, unsigned int stringPosStart; } map<strPos,vector<CitemElem*>>` but then I realized your idea is good. What i must do now is just check what part of the string the mouse is over! (Currently I can check only the item by returning the line id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, use a vector of `CItemElem*` as the  value in the map or, write another class that wraps it for more readability also considering the future need of adding any other type than `CItemElem`. Also if string position is a required key in finding the item, then a `map` can be used instead of a`vector`. Set each string position that spans the item to the pointer to that particular item so it can be easily retrieved when you have the string position in which the mouse is over.

```
class CLineElem
{

public:
void AddItemElem( CItemElem* pElem_i, int nStrPos_i );
CItemElem* GetItemElemAt( int nStrPos_i );
void RemoveAllItemElems();

private:
    map<unsigned int, CItemElem*> m_Elems;
};
```

Then use `CLineElem*` in the map `m_mItemChat` instead of `CItemElem*`

Comment: Thank you guys for the ideas! You've brightened me of how to store multiple items on the string and helped me to find out now I just need to calculate on what part of the string the mouse is over. The mouseover is detected by a render function, I'll calculate the  x and y mouse position along with the `<item>` position and the line Id, retrieving then one of the `CItemElem*` represented in the vector. From now and on it's with me, I just needed to lighten up! Thanks!